# How to write Unit test during development?

Tags: c, unit-testing, testing

Unit test is good for maintaining a software, especially if the maintainer is not very familiar with the whole system.

But I have a question here:

Before I complete the whole software system, how should I determine which functions I need write unit test for? In other word, what's the best granularity for unit test?

What's worse, The name or functionality of tested functions may be changed during the develop process or after time-to-time refactors, how should I maintain the unit test?

Comment: Generally speaking, one could say that any function which can give a value back (either trough a direct `return` Statement or by a reference argument) should be tested, as are all functions which can throw exceptions. And functions that doesn't return anything, but which can change state of something. And probably more.

Comment: You should probably ask at [programmers.se] instead.

Comment: In theory all functions, that are involved in production code (that is, code, that is running on production machine) should be covered by unit tests. These are subject to metric called [Code coverage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage). More is naturally better.

Comment: As for updating functions and tests, the test will simply fail to build if you change function names or signatures, telling what tests you need to update, Or follow more common [Test-driven development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) guidelines which says that tests comes first, so always update tests first and *then* update your functions.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, Thanks for your quick reply. Does that mean: During my development, if I add a function, I should write unit test for it, If I remove a function, I should remove the associated unit test.

Comment: [TDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) practices says to make the test *first*, and then make the function you're testing. And to update the test first, and when it fails you update the function it tries to test. And that to never change the tests so the pass, but instead change the functionality it tests.

Comment: @Juhana, When I was searching in Google, I was likely linked to here instead of  "Programmers". Maybe it's a good option. Thanks:)

Comment: Cool. I will look into the TDD wiki page first. Thank you so much.

Comment: @xjsXjtu: If you remove some function, then assiocated test(s) (likely) won't pass (as tested function is not found). That's why smart people invented tools for [Revision control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control), so test may be dropped, but it's still accessible from older revision.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I disagree that TDD requires to make the test first (and yes, Wikipedia page seem to be misleading in that matter). It may be written concurrently with code and that's OK.

Answer (score 2):

> how should I determine which functions I need write unit test for?

It is simple : try to unit test whatever you can, and try to get the unit tests coverage as high as possible. Of course, some things is not possible to unit test (access to specific HW, or DB) and some things should not be unit tested (functionality of an 3rd party library).

> what's the best granularity for unit test?

As said, try to have unit tests coverage as high as possible. Higher= better.

> The name or functionality of tested functions may be changed during the develop process or after time-to-time refactors, how should I maintain the unit test?

Treat unit tests as part of your code, and maintain them with the code. When the code change, change unit tests (modify, add and remove what is needed) to make them pass, and if possible increase unit tests coverage.

Answer (score 1):

TDD is easiest to start with. it says: never write any production code unless you have a falling test. so whenever you want to write a piece of production code, just stop. and think what should be the contract for this code. then write a test to check if the contract works. test will not compile because you have no code - so you have a red test. now you are allowed to write the code

so when you want to create a calculator you write a test:

```
int result = new Calculator().add(4,3);
assertThat(result).isEqual(7);
```

and now you know what code you should write

regarding test maintenance: tests are first class citizen, just as your production code. you have to maintain and refactor them just as production code. IDE helps significantly with that

Comment: in essence you say "write your specifications first". Indeed, write your specifications first! The test should follow from the specification automatically. And "A requirement for which you cannot devise a test is a bad requirement". The test you show follows from the requirement "The calculator shall be able to add two integer numbers".

Comment: That doesn't look like a c code, for which is harder to do TDD

Comment: @BЈовић i didn't say it's harder. i said that easiest way to start with testing is TDD. and that's an example of TDD

Comment: I said that it is very difficult to use TDD with C. With java, c++ and similar laguages, it is simple to use dependency injection, and mock something in unit tests. In C, you can use only function callbacks, and those are difficult to follow. Code and design with lots of function pointers is difficult to follow.

Comment: i'm not an expert in c++ but AFAIK concepts like TDD, IoC, composition, single responsibility are universal and not related to any specific technology or language. usually if you start from TDD your code is modular and cleaner. you don't have to do everything on function pointers

Answer (score 0):

Pragmatically speaking, you have to test first your class external interfaces (the public methods). You have to point on the "heavy" usage and provide the best coverage there. Generally, you should try to avoid to change your class interfaces drastically to ensure backward compatibility and allow your code be easy changing/refactoring. Therefore the appropriated test cases will probably also preserved.

Comment: there are no classes in c

Comment: Yes, the language not provides this option however you can do it by yourself even preparing the static library for the internal ("private") functions. Then you have to concentrate your test on the methods that other modules will call.